# Difference between multi year timeseries and it's 'standard year'

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, time-series

Assume I've a timeseries of a certain number of years as in:

```
rng = pd.date_range(start = '2001-01-01',periods = 5113)
ts = pd.TimeSeries(np.random.randn(len(rng)), rng)
```

Than I can calculate it's standard year (the average value of each day over all years) by doing:

```
std = ts.groupby([ts.index.month, ts.index.day]).mean()
```

Now I was wondering how I could subtract my multi-year timeseries from this standard year, in order to get a timeseries that show which days were below or above it's standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `groupby`, just subtract each group's mean from the values for that group:

```
average_diff = ts.groupby([ts.index.month, ts.index.day]).apply(
    lambda g: g - g.mean()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems it's working. Those `lambda`'s seems to do these things pretty well